# How to check if the inner list is not empty and the variable is not null using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

How to I combine this looping in a single stream?

```
final boolean hasEmptyFooDesc = data.getFoo().stream().anyMatch(fooDTO -> CollectionUtils.isEmpty(fooDTO.getFooDesc()));
final boolean hasDescriptions = data.getFoo().stream().flatMap(fooDTO -> fooDTO.getFooDesc().stream()).allMatch(fooDescDTO -> fooDescDTO.getDescription() != null); 
    
if (hasEmptyFooDesc || !hasDescriptions) {
 throw new BadRequestException();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a method e.g. `isBad`:

```
static boolean isBad(DtoType fooDto) {
  return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(fooDTO.getFooDesc())
      || fooDTO.getFooDesc().stream().anyMatch(fooDescDTO -> fooDescDTO.getDescription() == null);
}
```

and then invoke:

```
if (data.getFoo().stream().anyMatch(YourClass::isBad)) {
  throw ...
}
```

(Ofc, you don't *really* need the method here, you could write this as a lambda. But it's probably easier to read with a method).